# Elixir not starting up

Tags: erlang, elixir

I am trying to run v1.0 of Elixir and I've installed Erlang 17.4. When I try to run `iex` I get a series of errors that I don't understand:

```
$ iex -v

{error_logger,{{2015,11,11},{10,35,48}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{supervisor_bridge,user_sup,['Argument__1']}},{pid,<0.22.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{undef,[{'Elixir.IEx.CLI',start,[],[]},{user_sup,start_user,3,[{file,"user_sup.erl"},{line,99}]},{user_sup,init,1,[{file,"user_sup.erl"},{line,48}]},{supervisor_bridge,init,1,[{file,"supervisor_bridge.erl"},{line,79}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,306}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]},[{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,330}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}},{ancestors,[kernel_sup,<0.10.0>]},{messages,[]},{links,[<0.11.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,987},{stack_size,27},{reductions,176}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2015,11,11},{10,35,48}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,kernel_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{undef,[{'Elixir.IEx.CLI',start,[],[]},{user_sup,start_user,3,[{file,"user_sup.erl"},{line,99}]},{user_sup,init,1,[{file,"user_sup.erl"},{line,48}]},{supervisor_bridge,init,1,[{file,"supervisor_bridge.erl"},{line,79}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,306}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,user},{mfargs,{user_sup,start,[]}},{restart_type,temporary},{shutdown,2000},{child_type,supervisor}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2015,11,11},{10,35,48}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{application_master,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2','Argument__3','Argument__4']}},{pid,<0.9.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,user,{undef,[{'Elixir.IEx.CLI',start,[],[]},{user_sup,start_user,3,[{file,"user_sup.erl"},{line,99}]},{user_sup,init,1,[{file,"user_sup.erl"},{line,48}]},{supervisor_bridge,init,1,[{file,"supervisor_bridge.erl"},{line,79}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,306}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}},[{application_master,init,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,133}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}},{ancestors,[<0.8.0>]},{messages,[{'EXIT',<0.10.0>,normal}]},{links,[<0.8.0>,<0.7.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,610},{stack_size,27},{reductions,147}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2015,11,11},{10,35,48}},std_info,[{application,kernel},{exited,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,user,{undef,[{'Elixir.IEx.CLI',start,[],[]},{user_sup,start_user,3,[{file,"user_sup.erl"},{line,99}]},{user_sup,init,1,[{file,"user_sup.erl"},{line,48}]},{supervisor_bridge,init,1,[{file,"supervisor_bridge.erl"},{line,79}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,306}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}},{type,permanent}]}
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,user,{undef,[{'Elixir.IEx.CLI',start,[],[]},{user_sup,start_user,3,[{file,\"user_sup.erl\"},{line,99}]},{user_sup,init,1,[{file,\"user_sup.erl\"},{line,48}]},{supervisor_bridge,init,1,[{file,\"supervisor_bridge.erl\"},{line,79}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,306}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,\"proc_lib.erl\"},{line,237}]}]}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,user,{undef,[{'Elixir.IEx.CLI',start,[],[]},{user_sup,start_user,3,[{file,"user_su
```

I'm running Mac OS 10.10

Comment: Please be more specific about your OS.  This could be related to the OS which you've installed and without that knowledge it's tough to say what may be going on.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci sorry about that... The OS is MAC Yosemite.

Comment: How did you install Erlang/Elixir?

Comment: How do you start it? It looks like it can't elixir properly.

Comment: Can't  *find* elixir I mean of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like things are not properly installed.

Unless you have a special need to install it yourself, I'd recommend wiping out whatever you've done so far, then installing [the Homebrew package manager](http://brew.sh/) and then `brew install elixir`

Answer (score 0):

Try to find elixir in your local library and remove all.
then try to install with asdf:
`git clone https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf.git ~/.asdf --branch v0.6.3`

`echo -e '\n. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh' >> ~/.zshrc`

`echo -e '\n. $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash' >> ~/.zshrc`

Open a new iterm tab:

`asdf plugin-add erlang`

`asdf plugin-add elixir`

`brew install coreutils automake autoconf openssl libyaml readline libxslt libtool unixodbc`

`ERLANG_OPENSSL_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl" asdf install erlang <version>`

`asdf global erlang <version>`

`asdf install elixir <version>`

`asdf global elixir <version>`